# Is there a cap on the maximum image size that can be sent via worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I need to save an image to a folder via mobilefirst.The image will be uploaded from a mobile device . Is this a good option. If so , is there a cap on the image size.

Answer (score 0):

It's less about file size and more about how to handle the image file itself.

JavaScript adapters are not meant for handling binary files. You could encode the image to base64 and then use the Cordova File Transfer API or pure AJAX (and then decode the base64 string back to image/file form).

Another possibility for you is to send binary data (the image) by using Java adapters.